# WordPress 4.0 - Display author's content on custom post type

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

Here my problem.

- I have several users that are allowed to publish content.
- I have create a custom post type to be used has a personal page.
- I create a new custom post for each of the user.
- They can publish media, events, posts... on this custom post, using tools provided by the theme Flawless.

The Flawless tools publish by default all the content, so if you want to add a gallery, it will show all gallery by all users. I want to limit the gallery display to only the current author of the custom post. And the same for all type of content a user may want to add to his page.
My understanding was that `pre_get_posts` was perfect in this kind of situation.

The goal was to publish on their custom post only their content, so I used the action `pre_get_posts` with this function:

```
function only_current_author( $query ) {   

    if ( !is_admin() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'nav_menu_item' ) {  
        $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
        $author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
        $query->query_vars['author'] = "$author_id";
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_current_author' );
```

This was working fine on my localhost with WordPress 3.9

Now I have updated to WordPress 4.0, and I got an error 404.

I don't understand exactly what cause the issue, and what is different between the two WordPress version, but I think this is what caused the error 404 is that I'm not able to get the author id of the current custom post.

So, I wonder, do you know alternative to define the author id inside the `pre_get_posts` action ?
Or should I use another method to filter what will be display? 
I try several alternative, like adding an extra Query or adding the `$query->query_vars` in the template in my custom template, but none worked.
I try to get the author id using the name of the custom post found in the `$query`, nothing seems to work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

So, after a good night of sleep, I return to my problems and found a solution.
Thanks to give me your feedback if you think this solution is appropriate.

```
function only_current_author( $query ) {   

    if ( !is_admin() && $query->query_vars['post_type'] != 'nav_menu_item' ) {  

        global $wp_query;
        $post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
        $post_type = $wp_query->post->post_type;    

        if( $post_id != 0 && $post_type == 'cpt_mdj' ) {

            $post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
            $query->query_vars['author'] = $post_author_id;

        }

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'only_current_author' );
```

So, the issue was that `$post_id = get_queried_object_id();` returned null, from that it was impossible to pre filter the query with the author id.
Using $wp_query, I was able to get the post id, and then the author id.

Side question, what is the difference between $query and $wp_query, they are identical when I var_dump, but give different result.

Thanks!